# Git Bash Get Entire Repo of a Specific Build Version from Github

Tags: git, github, git-bash

What is the syntax and the commands to get the entire repo for a specific build version?

I am using Git Bash for Windows and am trying to get version [#1290] of the popcorn-js repo.

You can get the latest clone here:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js
```

But I want to get a previous version.

I have tried:

```
$ git revert #1290 git://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js
```

but I cannot find the syntax.

Comment: Are you just typing things at random and hoping they work? Because `#1290` has no meaning to git, and `revert` is entirely the wrong command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ git clone git://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js
$ cd popcorn-js
$ git checkout 35c805dab6a9ee39a75391a7d5476d306e3c4a86
```

[#1290](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js/commit/35c805dab6a9ee39a75391a7d5476d306e3c4a86)